# PHP array send json

Tags: php, arrays, json

i have this code

```
function get_data_tbl()
{
    $dt = $this->penilaian_model->get_data_tbl();
    foreach ($dt as $key => $value) {
        $date_in = $value->date_in;
        $nmloket = $value->nama;
        $keterangan = $value->keterangan;
        $sgtpuas = $value->sangat_puas;
        $puas = $value->puas;
        $tdkpuas = $value->tidak_puas;
        $total = $value->total;
        $nilai = $value->nilai;
        $output[] = [$date_in.','.$nmloket.','.$keterangan.','.$sgtpuas.','.$puas.','.$tdkpuas.','.$total.','.$nilai];            
    }
    send_json($output);
}
```

and this the output

> [ ["2017-03-16,A,Informasi,0,1,0,1,60"] , ["2017-03-16,C,Tanggapan SPHP,0,1,0,1,60"] ]

but i want the output like this

> [ ["2017-03-16" , "A" , "Informasi" , "0" , "1" , "0" , "1" , "60"] , ["2017-03-16" , "C" , "Tanggapan SPHP" , "0" , "1" , "0" , "1" , "60"] ]

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want them to be separate array elements, don't concatenate them with `.`. That makes a single string.

```
$output[] = [$date_in, $nmloket, $keterangan, $sgtpuas, $puas, $tdkpuas, $total, $nilai];
```